# ReactNative - Animate multiple views size based on condition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I have a view full of red circles.

I would like to animate their size/borderRadius based on which circle is highlighted (**biggerCircleIndex**)

The code looks like this now:

```
import React from 'react';

const Circles = props => {

  const myCircles = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const [biggerCircleIndex, setBiggerCircleIndex] = useState(2);
 
  return (
    <View>
      {myCircles.map((index) => {
         return (
            <Animated.View
              key={index}
              style={[
                {backgroundColor: 'red'},
                (biggerCircleIndex == index)
                  ? {width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 50}
                  : {width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 25},
              ]}>
            </Animated.View>
          );
      })}
    </View>
  );
};
export {Circles};
```

Tried using animation for the size but failed: the circles aren't animated when I update the **biggerCircleIndex**

I think I should create an array of animations, but I really don't know how.

Can someone help me out?

Here's the code snippet how I've been trying:

```
import React from 'react';

const Circles = props => {

  const myCircles = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const [biggerCircleIndex, setBiggerCircleIndex] = useState(2);

  const inputRange = [0, 100];
  const outputRange = [50, 100];

  const animation = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current
  const animatedSize = animation.interpolate({inputRange, outputRange});

  const animationReverse = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(100)).current
  const animatedSizeReverse = animationReverse.interpolate({inputRange, outputRange});

  React.useEffect(() => {
      Animated.timing(
          animation,
          {
            toValue: 100,
            duration: 500,
            useNativeDriver: false,
          }
      ).start();
  }, [animation])
  React.useEffect(() => {
      Animated.timing(
          animationReverse,
          {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: 500,
            useNativeDriver: false,
          }
      ).start();
  }, [animationReverse])

  return (
    <View>
      {myCircles.map((index) => {
         return (
            <Animated.View
              key={index}
              style={[
                {backgroundColor: 'red'},
                (biggerCircleIndex == index)
                  ? {width: animatedSize, height: animatedSize, borderRadius: 50}
                  : {width: animatedSizeReverse, height: animatedSizeReverse, borderRadius: 25},
              ]}>
            </Animated.View>
          );
      })}
    </View>
  );
};
export {Circles};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For achieving this, I think one of the best approaches is creating an independent `Circle` component. That way, each circle would have its own `Animated.Value`.

Also, since you only want to animate the `radius` (`height` and `width` are the same value) and `borderRadius` (which is half the `radius`) we'd only need two `Animated.Value`'s.

We'd also need something to trigger the animation. In your example, I think the animations are triggered when the component mounts. Here I created an `animate` prop for each circle, so that the animation runs when this prop changes.

The circle component could be something like this:

```jsx
function Circle({ animate }) {
  const radius = useRef(new Animated.Value(50)).current;
  const borderRadius = Animated.divide(radius, 2);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (animate) {
      // if this circle is selected, we animate it
      Animated.timing(radius, {
        toValue: 100,
        duration: 500,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }).start();
    }
    // if it isn't being selected we animate it back
    else {
      Animated.timing(radius, {
        toValue: 50,
        duration: 500,
        useNativeDriver: false,
      }).start();
    }
  }, [animate, radius]);

  return (
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        height: radius,
        width: radius,
        borderRadius: borderRadius,
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

We need only one `useEffect` which runs when `animate` changes. If it changes to `true` we should trigger the growing animation, if it changes to `false` we should trigger the shrinking animation.

Then, the parent component (`Circles`) could just control which circle is selected. I wrapped each circle in a `Touchable` just so it's easier to change the selected circle, and to trigger the animations:

```jsx
const Circles = (props) => {
  const myCircles = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const [biggerCircleIndex, setBiggerCircleIndex] = useState(2);

  return (
    <View>
      {myCircles.map((index) => {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setBiggerCircleIndex(index)}>
            <Circle animate={index === biggerCircleIndex} key={`${index}`} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
};
```

There are probably other approaches to achieving this, maybe you could, as you suggested, make this work by creating an array of `Animated.Value`'s.

I hope this helps!

Uploaded this code to a [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@joaocout/vigorous-carrot).

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate your detailed answer! This is what I was looking for, with this logic it works smoothly! :)